# Does Tor work with WebRTC?

Tags: browsers

[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is yet another technology that has the possibility to change the face of the web, but is it supported in Tor ?

Searching the tor-dev mailing, there is [this thread on the WebRTC](http://www.mail-archive.com/tor-talk@lists.torproject.org/msg08733.html) but it is unclear if there is official enduser support, or even if realtime communications are even viable given the latency introduced by the anonymizing process.

Comment: media.peerconnection.enabled works perfectly in Tor Browser ! A normal web chat works. E.g. https://rtccopy.com/#kaffeestuebchen Warning : Never download or Upload a File in this chatroom !

Comment: That is not working in my Tor Browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tor Browser is [built without WebRTC support](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8178), since WebRTC can be used to circumvent Tor's proxy settings via [ICE over UDP](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch18.html).

In Firefox, WebRTC support is [controlled](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963501) by `media.peerconnection.enabled` preference, and it's set to `false` by default in Tor Browser. But, even enabling this preference would not turn WebRTC on, since the Firefox binary does not contain the functionality.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for this post, upvoted. I just asked a related question regarding WebRTC and wondered if you could let me know your thoughts? https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14660/getting-webrtc-on-tor